# Reduce the size of image picker for camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

My Question is regarding image picker (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera). When I press take photo in my iphone App, the default size is 320x480. How can I change this to any other dimension, e.g. 320x200 or any other in both landscape and portrait?

```
m_pImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
m_pImagePickerController.delegate = self;
[m_pImagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:m_pImagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codza.com/custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-view

I'm using the following code to scale down images after retrieving from picker.

Code:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

        UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;

}
```

Comment: i am talking about camera view...not about picture